# MVC not returning proper file type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I wrote a basic `FilePathResult` in my MVC 5 Application to return a file.  The file type that isnt returning correctly is a `.xlsx`.  `PDF's` and other files work fine.

```
public FilePathResult Download(int? id)
{
    var model = db.DisciplineModels.Where(x=>x.Id == id).Include(i=>i.Employee).FirstOrDefault();
    string username = model.Employee.FirstName + " " + model.Employee.LastName;
    string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(model.Report_Filename);
    string path = string.Format(@"~/Employee Records/{0}/HR/Discipline/{1}", username, model.Report_Filename);
    return new FilePathResult(path, mimeType);
}
```

My `mimeType` is coming back with the correct file type of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and the file path is correct (the file is there in the folder).  Everything seems to work fine, until it passes the file to the browser for download.  It comes back as a file with no extension.  I do not have Office installed on this computer, but that should matter? (Its a development machine, no need for office).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a typo in `.xlxs`?

Comment: Yes, I mean .xlsx. updated

Comment: What is actual `model.Report_Filename` value for `.xlsx` file?

Comment: `model.Report_Filename` comes out as `Discipline_20160422T130831.xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Begin Edit**

According to the [Controller source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs):

```
protected internal virtual FilePathResult File(string fileName, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
{
    return new FilePathResult(fileName, contentType) { FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName };
}
```

So for your case you may try to use `return new FilePathResult(path, mimeType) { FileDownloadName = model.Report_Filename };` which is the same as `return File(path, mimeType, model.Report_Filename);`

**End Edit**

Try adding the following section to your `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Same thing happens.  File comes out without an extension

Comment: @Shawn Gavett, may the reason be in the too long `path`?

Comment: @Shawn Gavett, try `return new FilePathResult(model.Report_Filename, mimeType);`

Comment: doubtful, a `pdf` with the same file name (the timestamp format) works just fine.  Hmm, `.csv` doesnt work either.  Now that I think about it, I used a Response and `memorystream` to export other excel files in my project.  I can just use that code to make this work.  Weird that `FilePathResult` wont work with `xls, xlsx, csv` files.

Comment: If I do that, MVC wont know where to get the file from.  It will search the root level of my application.  Tried it and it produced that error.

Comment: @Shawn Gavett, yeah. Right. Still try checking out what do you have in MIME types section in your IIS. There should probably be some difference between `.pdf` and `.xlsx`.

Comment: Yes, the edit would work as well.  Basically mimics `File()` like you said.  Thank you for your help Ivan

Answer (score 1):

By changing the return type from `FilePathResult` to `File`, I was able to get it to behave as expected.

Changed this `return new FilePathResult(path, mimeType);` to `return File(path, mimeType, model.Report_Filename);`

Not sure why `FilePathResult` didnt work for this. (Any insight is greatly appreciated).

Comment: Same as `return new FilePathResult(path, mimeType) { FileDownloadName = model.Report_Filename };` according to [sources](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs) (seek for `File` method). Probably in case `.pdf` browser is capable of deducing the correct name by itself.